# Why is this nav menu flickering?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-template

I have been trying to debug this for so long so I thought I could bounce some ideas / get some direction as to *why* this is happening...

[once the page loads and you hover over the dropdowns,](https://2olxska475kq1fbi-22191211.shopifypreview.com) there is a flicker where the dropdown initiates. any clues as to why? thanks in advance!!!

Comment: when you check the behavior of the menu there is a certain height that is applied with some CSS, after you of the animation and height from the child it works much smoothly as compared to now. https://prnt.sc/z6c13f

Comment: @Onkar thank you so much!! this worked. Is there any way you can help me debug the mobile menu? it's so glitchy as well and i don't know why. been trying for an hour now!!

Comment: glad to know it helps you, can you let me know what glitch into a mobile menu?

Comment: @Onkar on IOS (safari, iphone), the live site (https://www.kaiser.kg/) has a smooth transitional nav toggle in the hamburger menu. however, i'm updating the clients theme to 5 versions newer, and this version (https://2olxska475kq1fbi-22191211.shopifypreview.com/) has a buggy nav menu on mobile. Let me know if you see the difference? ps thank you, you are a blessing. i'm so stuck.

Comment: In your newer theme it seems once the submenu is opened it doesn't close again, is it the issue?

Comment: There is the CSS add to the desktop version I think and it causes conflict with a menu in mobile devices.https://prnt.sc/zb15ie. you need to wrap this CSS into media query like `@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {// this CSS will only be used when the screen size is min 800px}`, so this run over the devices like tablet and desktop not over mobile.

Comment: @Onkar you are a genius, seriously, thank you. How did you find this conflict in css? I need to learn your debugging skills!!